# １つのフォームに（form_with）に複数ボタンを設置、かつimage_submit_tagで異なる機能を呼び出したい。

Tags: javascript, ruby, jquery

## 前提・実現したいこと

１つのフォームに（form_with）に複数ボタンを設置、かつimage_submit_tagで異なる機能を呼び出したい。
以下コードの場合、更新、削除ボタンを実装したい
http://yiaowang.web.fc2.com/programing/ruby_base/rails_views_submit.html

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

参考サイトでは、submit_tagだが、画像からsubmitしたいので、image_submit_tagを使いたい。しかし、パラメーターが異なるため、ボタンに条件分岐の起点となるvalue値を付与できない。
https://lealog.hateblo.jp/entry/2012/11/04/121603

## 該当のソースコード

```
      .masterSSS
        = form_with(id: "editFormSSS", model: @user_sss, url:user_sss_path(@user_sss.ids), local: true, method: :put) do |f|
          %h3 詳細項目
          %table
            %tr
              %th 生徒名
              %td
                = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name", id: "editInputStudent"
          .Trash
            = image_submit_tag "delete.png"
          %menu
            %li.actions
              = image_submit_tag("update.png")
```

## 自分で調べたことや試したこと

1. [submit_tagにvalueを指定、パラメーターに飛ばす](http://yiaowang.web.fc2.com/programing/ruby_base/rails_views_submit.html)ことで、controller側で条件分岐でvalue基準で区別
   →パラメーターにvalueを飛ばせず、submit_tagでは条件分岐ができない
2. submit_tagにcssでbackground-url指定できるが、valueをsubmit_tagに指定すると画像と被ってしまう　[参考元](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322441/adding-image-into-submit-tag-in-rails/31323472)
   →value指定すると、viewにテキストが表示されてしまい使えず
3. jQueryで２つのimage_submit_tagにonsubmitで判定する　[参考サイト](https://www.koikikukan.com/archives/2018/11/29-000300.php)
   →知識不足で、jqueryからform_withのhttpリクエストをDELETEにする方法がわからない

## 使っているツールのバージョンなど補足情報

ruby 2.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

削除したいだけであれば、フォームと紐付ける必要はないと思います。
具体的には、

```rb
link_to(@user_sss, method: :delete) do
  image_tag('delete.png')
end
```

みたいなコードでいい感じにできるかもしれません。